# Client DOM XSS, Checkmarx flagging JavaScript/jQuery code, sanitization help needed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom, xss, checkmarx

I have a legacy custom script that manipulates existing HTML via the jQuery append() method.

This is being flagged by Checkmarx with an error message similar to:

> The application's functionXXX embeds untrusted data in the generated output with append, at line XXX. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.

I'm having to update this code, so I'm taking a look at third party JS libraries like XSS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss) or dompurify (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) which use white lists.

My issue is there are a lot of HTML tags in this script being manipulated with jQuery. Elements such as table, tr, td, a, input, select, etc. and various attributes. The attribute list has to include multiple aria-xxx tags such as aria-disabled, aria-owns, aria-pressed, ad nauseam for jQuery UI to work.

It may be possible to add hooks to dompurify, and I think I could allow any attribute starting with "aria-". This seems like an ugly solution.

I just want the code to be safe with any <script> tags and other potential XSS to be removed. I could write my own sanitizer function but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel and Checkmarx still may not pass my new code if it isn't thorough enough. There are so many different attack vectors and variations.

Is there anything out there such as a different library or a common list of elements that can be white listed or a better way to do this? What's the accepted practice here?

Here is the part of the code Checkmarx is flagging.

```js
var $clone;
switch ($context.get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
    case "table":
        if ($context.find("tbody").length == 0) {
            $clone = $entityRangeTemplate.find("tbody").clone();
            $context.append($clone);
        } else {
            $clone = $entityRangeTemplate.find("tr").clone();

            $context.find("tbody").append($clone);
        }
        break;
    case "tbody":
        $clone = $entityRangeTemplate.find("tr").clone();
        $context.append($clone);
        break;
    default:
        return;
} //switch $clone
```

Comment: by looking at the code i´d say you can ignore the checkmarx hint, I dont see how this applies to xss

Comment: Inspecting the DOM of the aspx page where this script is used, I see several <textarea> elements that are being manipulated. 
I've read of issues with the <textarea> element and HTML tags.
Could that be the reason it's being flagged?

Comment: Also, the version of jQuery UI being used is 1.8.17 and jQuery version 1.7.1
I've attempted to upgrade jQuery to version 3.5 but multiple issues appear and everything breaks.

Comment: it´s important that the appended contents not come from an url-parameter or from the server after being send via free form from the client. That would be the "injection"